# How to access images from different drawable folders

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image, android-drawable

I have created an application which runs on a mobile device. But now I want it to run on Tablet too. I have defined maximum of my images in "Drawable-mdpi" folder and a few of them resized for xhdpi screens and stored them in "Drawable-xhdpi" folder. When I try to run the app on Tablet the images from xhdpi folder are not getting accessed. Can anyone give me some solution to the problem.

Comment: You can create aliases to your resources, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources

Comment: What are the resolutions of your devices?

Comment: 1200x800 is the resolution of the device which i tested

Answer (score 0):

You're struggeling with "device fragmentation" - a major difficulty in Android development.

You should be aware, that screen size and density are independent from each other. A huge screen can have a low density and a small screen a huge density. Devices can also have a different screen size and still have the same density.

In your case you have a tablet with medium density and a phone with medium density. That's why Android will pick the mdpi-folder, no matter if you use your tablet or your phone.

In order to solve that problem, you have to give your tablet the opporunity to pick its images out of a different folder - but it still should be mdpi. In order to do that, you **add a new drawable folder called "drawable-xlarge-mdpi"**. Put the images for your tablet into the new folder and keep the images for your phone in "drawable-mdpi".

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html